# MVC: Pass HTML template in JSON response rather than separate resource?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, templates, asynchronous

I'm planning to write a web app using either Backbone or Angular. We want to push "widgets" from the server to the client (i.e. semi-complicated, dynamic but largely autonomous UI elements... something maybe like the popular TodoMVC app). So we'll need to send over a template, some javascript (controllers etc.), probably CSS, and JSON data (models).

We're debating how to send over all the information. How much can be, and what should be encapsulated in the JSON?

Is it possible to create files out of data passed over? i.e. could we pull out CSS and apply the rules to our document? I believe it would be easier to run javascript passed over this way.

I'm under the impression that being able to cache the template is important... does that require loading it as a (separate) resource rather than as part of some huge JSON object?

As for CSS, it needs to be loaded before inserting into the DOM (so we don't want just a promise). Would it make sense - or even be possible - to pass our CSS rules in the JSON and extract them somehow?

**EDIT**: to more fully describe what I'm working with, I'm focusing only on the front-end. The back-end can be customized to send over resources however we want - they'll optimize that depending on what the front-end needs. Our backend stack includes MongoDB, Tapestry, ActiveMQ.

The payload that needs to get sent over will be all the resources necessary to push something like a Mac Dashboard Widget or Windows Gadget into the browser. So HTML, CSS, Javascript, data will all get sent over.  We want things to be snappy and minimize server requests as much as possible, as some of these payloads may get to be somewhat large.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions are rather vague and the answers can change by coding on a different build platform.  Your chosen application design can also impact the best practices to follow for implementing X type of application to X device(s).  There's more than one way to skin a cat ya know.

What information are you sending over?  Is it a lot of raw data arrays?  Is it more document based where XML could be more beneficial?  You'll need to work with your DBA if the data is stored in a repository and you'll be querying it.  Will you need to write code to format your data or will the DBMS output it in the format you need?

What do you mean the CSS needs to be loaded before being inserted?  Everything loads in the order you specify so making sure your CSS loads at the proper time shouldn't be an issue.  If you're using ASP.NET, you can also use a [SSM](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/stylesheetmanager.aspx) (style-sheet manager) to serve your CSS and only load whats required.  SSM's are great if you have a lot of style-sheets to serve.

A lot of the questions you asked will be answered as you get further into the design phase.  In order to get some solid answers and not just speculation on what is the best method, you will need to publish a lot more details than this.  Any answers at this point shouldn't carry much weight in your decisions.  They certainly wouldn't mine.

Comment: Yes, you could send CSS rules in a JSON dataset but why?  You'd then have to build the CSS rules for the browser and apply them to the view.  I guess if that's your only option or you have an amazing method of assembling and applying the CSS it makes sense.  I haven't gotten much into mobile development but in 13+ years I've never had the business need to implement or serve CSS in any special format.

Comment: thanks for the response! made an edit to clarify some of your questions.